# MeshLab .ply file import error

Tags: meshlab

Im new to 3D reconstruction i have point cloud. and i write it on .ply file.But when i press on it file

Meshlab provides me an Error . please find the below and meshlab could allow open that file

```
 Unespected eof
```

please find my bunney(copy).ply file

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment Mars model by Paul Bourke
element vertex 259200
property float x
property float y
property float z
element face 516960
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
15081.5 -3.45644e+06 65.8061
15081 -3.45659e+06 197.422
15078.2 -3.45648e+06 329.009
15075.4 -3.45663e+06 460.597
15071.2 -3.4567e+06 592.148
15065.6 -3.45674e+06 723.653
15059.9 -3.457e+06 855.16
15050.7 -3.45674e+06 986.473
14541.2 3.33642e+06 -698.464
14547.7 3.33663e+06 -571.58
14551.5 3.33649e+06 -444.589
14552.7 3.336e+06 -317.541
14556.9 3.33645e+06 -190.56
14558.7 3.33661e+06 -63.5247
3 0 721 1
3 721 0 720
3 1 722 2
3 722 1 721
3 2 723 3
3 723 2 722
```

get rid of that error what should i change in my bunney(copy).ply ? please help me.

Please find below the image
[image: Error MeshLab]

Comment: having the same problem. I found this one here: http://sourceforge.net/p/meshlab/bugs/238/ but "export LANG=C" doesnt help in my case.

Comment: I ran into this issue as well, and did the following: Change scientific notation to decimal, removed comment lines, as well as some other things that are not relevant here and was able to load it.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, the data was correct however not read properly by meshlab due to locale settings. Once restarted the program using `LC_ALL=C meshlab`, the ply finally loaded. Version 2016.12.

Comment: Specifically, this is due to the environment variable `LC_NUMERIC` being set to a locale that uses `,` for the decimal place separator. You really only have to change it to a local that uses `.` or to C. E.g., `export LC_NUMERIC='en_US.UTF-8'` or `export LC_NUMERIC=C`

Comment: @stephen I am not so well versed with Locale Environment Variables. If you are very sure, let me know or I will read on this once free and then update the answer. And thank you :)

Comment: Your answer is fine. I was just providing more details and being more specific about the cause of the problem, since it appears in other programs as well. You could replace `LC_ALL` with `LC_NUMERIC` in your answer and it would solve the comma issue. However, I have not extensively used meshlab so perhaps there is additional functionality affected by `LC_ALL`, so I would leave the answer as is.

Comment: @snwflk LOL, its alright. Working/Studying in germany, so was easy for me to catch as my system locale is set to deutch language.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in your ply file:

`element vertex 259200`

and

`element face 516960`

It means your ply file contains data of 259200 vertices and 516960 faces. However, your ply file does not have those much data. So the MeshLab would show errors " Unespected eof".

You need to confirm that your ply file has as much data as you describe.

Comment: Sorry I'm a very beginner, but how to onfirm that your ply file has as much data as I describe ?

Comment: For example, `element vertex 259200` means you have 259200 vertex, you just need to confirm your ply file contains data of 259200 vertex.

Comment: Yea I understood that, but what do you mean by confirm. MeshLab is not asking any confirmation. It just says "Error details: Unespected eof" and I don't have other option than press "ok". Am I supposed to add someting in the .ply file or to change an option in MeshLab ?

Comment: MeshLab does not warn you. You need to check it by yourself and then load it ito MeshLab.

Comment: At the end I just replace the "." by "," and it works

Answer (score -3):

Try putting a blank line at the end of your file.
This may or may not resolve your problem.

Comment: @kipe but end of the file always have blank space . any idea dude